# Вызываем бесконечный генератор в Python

Tags: python

Есть найденная функция генераторная erat3, которая выдает простые числа. Как наиболее просто ее вызывать, если хотим получить список простых чисел, меньших n?

Comment: Функцию покажите..

Comment: @Alban думаю, для ответа на вопрос в этом нет смысла. Достаточно знать, что `for i in erat3(): print(i)` печатает `2 3 5 7 11 13 17` и так далее до бесконечности (если я правильно понял вопрос)

Comment: там есть yield, который

Comment: По моему лучше всего модифицировать функцию, чтобы она принимала n

Comment: http://qaru.site/questions/9543/how-to-implement-an-efficient-infinite-generator-of-prime-numbers-in-python

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, я думаю, лучше давать ссылку на оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796442/4752653

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно попробовать использовать функцию takewhile из библиотеки itertools.

Она принимает любой итерируемый объект и условие, и возвращает элементы итерируемого объекта до тех пор, пока условие не будет нарушено.

То есть вот этот код по идее должен сделать именно то, что вы хотите:

```
from itertools import takewhile

result = list(takewhile(lambda x: x < n, erat3()))
```

Comment: А если нужно брать числа в интервале, скажем только трехзначныы?

Comment: filter зависает

Comment: result = list(dropwhile(lambda x: x<100, takewhile(lambda x: x < 1000, erat3())))